# How does OrderBy function on equal values

Tags: .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have a simple `IEnumerable<TKey>` to order and export to array.

Depending on `TKey`, if I use the `OrderBy` LINQ extension and the values of `TKey` are equal in the entire sequence, can I rely that the elements in the `IEnumerable` will retain their original index (when relevant, i.e. array etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

As the documentation says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved.

So if *all* of the elements in the list are equal, they will retain their index. And if just a few elements in the list are equal, they will retain their original order with respect to each other (but their indices will of course change, as the list has been sorted).